# disabled textbox displaying value

Tags: php, mysql

i have a book form in which there is an ID field. i'd like the [disabled] textbox to display the ID from mysql when the user tries to fill the form.

it should check the database for the last id and accordingly display the next id. for example, if the last id entered is 8, then it should display to the new user- 9. how would i pre-generate the textbox to show the id?

Comment: you need php code or sql query to get the last id?

Comment: You shouldn't do this, what happens if two users want to enter an new row to the db at the same time. they will both get the same number in the form!

Comment: @sAc - php code

@ Jens F. - what then is the best way to go about doing this? the reason why i need the book id is the because the content being updated is dependent on the id.

Comment: what do you mean by "because the content being updated is dependent on the id." some sample code would be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the id column in MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT` so the id is increment automatically on every insert. Then get the inserted id through `PDO::lastInsertId` or `mysql_insert_id`. No need to display to the user.

Comment: thanks for this. but what if i want the id BEFORE the insertion?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to display this information to the user.  Use an `auto_increment` primary key field and once the user submits the form, insert a `NULL` value for that field in your insert statement.  When an `auto_increment` field is passed a `NULL` value, it will insert the next value in the sequence.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html